# Is it possible to change the Microsoft Lync keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, lync

Pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> key combination currently opens the minimized Lync client.  I want to remove that mapping.  Is it possible to change it?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If another application that runs before Lync in the login sequence sets a Win-Q system hot key, that application will get the assignment instead of Lync. I like to use Win-Q as the hot key for the SlickRun launcher utility, and it will "steal" the key from Lync if they are both set to auto-start.

Comment: Slickrun is the app that prompted this question.  I simply changed Lync to not start with Windows and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Lync's Ctrl-Shift-S (Stop Screen Sharing) interferes w/ Visual Studio's "Save All". The following failed to resolve this problem for me (Lync 2010): 1) Uncheck Lync's "Automatically start..." option 2) Gently close Lync 3) Reboot 4) Observe Lync *not* start automatically post-reboot 5) Start VS and create unsaved changes in editor 6) Start Lync 7) Share Screen w/ Lync contact 8) Return VS window to forefront 9) Type Ctrl-Shift-S 10) Observe Lync perform its "Stop Screen Sharing" command 11) Observe VS has not performed its "Save All" command

Comment: Just for reference: There is second thread from you, where a script option was linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452831/perform-saveall-in-visual-studio-while-sharing-screen-via-lync